# How to capture iOS Safari event on text selection change within Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ios, events, safari, selection

Following scenario: When selecting text on iOS Safari (lets assume a "normal" html page) an blue overlay occurs, indicating that you have selected a specific passage. Furthermore, you are able to change that selection, in order to correct your initial selection area. I'm interested in capturing exactly that event, when selection area change is done. Is it possible (when yes, how?) to catch such an event within Javascript? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Mobile Safari supports the `selectionchange` event, which fires on `Document` nodes:

```
document.addEventListener("selectionchange", function() {
    alert("Selection changed!");
}, false);
```

Comment: Thank you. selectionchange did the trick! Unfortunately, it does not carry any information about the selection itself, right? When inspecting touchend event for instance, I can find helpful information about x/y coordinates or selection range.

Comment: @Marco: The selection is accessible via `window.getSelection()` and is updated by the time `selectionchange` fires.

Answer (score 3):

I've found that this event fires multiple times even on a single word selection (with a tap),
and of course it fires when you drag the selection handles ...

I created a small workaround to get only the text selection end event.

you can see it **here**: [End of text selection event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076173/end-of-text-selection-event)

or in a small post on **my blog**:  http://www.dimshik.com/end-of-text-selection-event-on-ios-workaround/