# End of text selection event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

Is there an event for the end of text selection on iOS?

I know I can run an event when the selection changes through the following:

```
document.addEventListener("selectionchange", function(event) {
        var text = window.getSelection().toString();
        $(".output").append("<div>" + text + "</div>");
}, false);

<div class="output"></div>
```

This will update `.output` with the selected text, but runs every time the selection changes. What I would want, is to only capture the text after the selection has finished.

Is there any such event? Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 11):

How about binding a `mouseup` event?

JAVASCRIPT:

```
document.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
        var text = window.getSelection().toString();
    $(".output").append("<div>" + text + "</div>");
}, false);
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/yTMwu/66/

Comment: No, `mouseup` is not triggered when the finger leaves the screen on iOS.

Comment: I wish :\ If you were to select text, then release your finger, `touchend` is not called. If, however, you then tap somewhere within the selection, it calls `touchend`.

Comment: `pointerup` event will work with both mouse and finger. https://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents3/#the-pointerup-event

Answer (score 7):

Similar to you i didn't found a good solution for this problem, So i decided to create a workaround.
it's not the prettiest but it works.

I created a timeout function and bind it to a "onselectionchange" event.
Each time the event fired i check if my timeout is running, and if so i delete it and create a new one.

when the timeout is finished a custom event "selectionEnd" is fired.

```
// bind selection change event to my function
document.onselectionchange = userSelectionChanged;

function userSelectionChanged() {

    // wait 500 ms after the last selection change event
    if (selectionEndTimeout) {
        clearTimeout(selectionEndTimeout);
    }

    selectionEndTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        $(window).trigger('selectionEnd');
    }, 500);
}

$(window).bind('selectionEnd', function () {

    // reset selection timeout
    selectionEndTimeout = null;

    // TODO: Do your cool stuff here........

    // get user selection
    var selectedText = getSelectionText();

    // if the selection is not empty show it :)
    if(selectedText != ''){
       // TODO: Do something with the text
    }
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dimshik/z8Jge/

I wrote a small post about it in my blog: http://www.dimshik.com/end-of-text-selection-event-on-ios-workaround/

Comment: Interesting... I wonder if there would be anyway to only log the text once the finger has been released from the screen. As of now, this will run when the selection has stopped changing, but not when the finger has completely finished selecting.

Answer (score 5):

I'm also facing this problem, since I haven't found a good solution this is my workaround.
It will fire a `selectionEnd` event when user confirm his selection pressing confirm/back button in the mobile browser Clipboard.

```
var longpress = false;
var longpressTimer = null;
var loop = null;
var latestSelection = null;

window.ontouchstart = function(){
    longpressTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        longpress = true;
        loop = setInterval(getSelection, 200);
    }, 500)
};

window.ontouchend = function(){
    if(longpressTimer){
        clearTimeout(longpressTimer);
    }
    longpress = false;
}

var getSelection = function (){
    var s = window.getSelection();
    if(s.rangeCount > 0){
        latestSelection = s.getRangeAt(0);
    }else{
        clearInterval(loop);
        var selEndEvent = new CustomEvent("selectionEnd", {"detail": latestSelection});
        window.dispatchEvent(selEndEvent);
    }
}
```

When a long-press is performed, it starts a interval to monitor the selection. Then user confirms his selection and the clipboard automatically deletes it; that breaks the monitor loop and sends the selectionEnd event.
You can access the last selected text in detail property.

I hope to get some news about this problem and to get a better solution.