# Bookmarklet to go to URL based on selected text

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

How could I write a bookmarklet for Google Chrome that will take the selected text, append it to a predetermined URL, and then go to the modified URL.

For example, let's say the base URL is `http://www.mybaseurl.com/`. (This base URL is hardcoded in the bookmarklet code.)  Now, suppose that on a random webpage I select the text `dog`.  Then, if I click the bookmarklet while that text is selected, I want the bookmarklet to cause the browser to visit the following URL: `http://www.mybaseurl.com/dog`.

How can this be done?

Comment: Clicking the bookmark will de-select the text. You'd need to continually capture what's selected.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21026569/how-to-capture-event-on-text-selection

Comment: You could start by storing the selected text as a variable using `window.getSelection()` although browser compatibility is not very good. I know older versions of IE use `document.selection` and as @Diodeus said, as soon as the user clicks the bookmarklet, the text will become unselected.

Comment: @Diodeus but, [this blog post](http://arcadiamashups.blogspot.com/2009/10/get-selection-bookmarklet-pattern.html) looks like that isn't true. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the currently selected text with [`window.getSelection()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getSelection). So this bookmarklet can redirect based on the selected text:

```
javascript:window.location.href="http://www.mybaseurl.com/"+window.getSelection()
```

Answer (score 1):

This method will open the url in a new window or tab (depending on browser settings), instead of opening the url in the current tab. So, you won't lose your place. It uses `window.open` instead of `location=`

```
javascript:(function(){s=document.selection?document.selection.createRange().text:window.getSelection?window.getSelection().toString():document.getSelection?document.getSelection():'';if(s==''){s=prompt('You%20did%20not%20select%20any%20text%20to%20search%20for.%20Enter%20the%20text%20to%20search%20for%20:','');}if(s){window.open('https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=ptr%3a'+s,  '_blank')};})()
```