# No Javascript event in iOS when lifting finger after long press?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, ipad

I'm trying to detect when a user has finished resizing a text selection on iOS, using Javascript.

While I'm aware of the `selectionchange` even , if the user uses the native controls I'll get a lot of `scroll` events, and a few `selectionchange`.

Now, I have no idea when the user is done, however. If he spends 5 minutes with his finger down, without moving the controls nor changing the selection, I don't get a "`mouseup` equivalent" event.

EDIT: ...my situation is basically this one: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/Art/events_information_bubble.jpg

Any idea how this could be achieved?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not listen for touchend events?

Comment: Doesn't fire one. Looks like if the element receiving the event is a native UI control, touchend is not fired (well, I'm not sure about this, but in my case only scroll gets fired and nothing after that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that `selectionchange` event fires multiple times even on a single word selection (with a tap or a long press), and of course it fires when you drag the selection handles ...

Here is a workaround i have created (not a perfect one) to get only the text selection end event.

you can see it **here**: [End of text selection event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076173/end-of-text-selection-event)

or in a small post on **my blog**: http://www.dimshik.com/end-of-text-selection-event-on-ios-workaround/

Comment: Yep. That's what I'm doing, too. I guess there is no solution but that. Can you confirm that touchend events are not fired (perhaps because the handles are not part of the webpage, but the OS)..?