# How to detect contenteditable cursor position change Safari + iPad + IOS 7?

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, contenteditable

When using contenteditable (on HTML5) you can listen to click/touch and key events to detect when the cursor position changes. It seems on iPad / Safari nothing fires when using a touch event to reposition the cursor.

Is there a method to detect the cursor position change?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On WebKit and derivatives (including Safari, Chrome and Mobile Safari), and IE, you can use the `selectionchange` event of the document:

```
document.onselectionchange = function() {
    console.log("Selection changed!");
};
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/13881312/96100

Comment: It seems a cursor reposition itself does not fire a selection change.

Comment: I tried to hook the event up to my textarea, but unless it's bound to document it won't work. Binding to document is key.

Comment: @Diodeus: Yes, that's why I explicitly suggested binding to the document :) Glad you got it working.